# VB6 - break program until a button is clicked

Tags: vb6

I'm using VB6 and I'm trying to do the following:

I have a command button that execute a while statement. in this statement I'm loading a new form with:

```
Load FrmPayment
FrmPayment.Show
```

I want the program to brake until I click a button in the new form, and then start from the same point I left

I tried looking the web for an answer but couldn't find anything that helped.

How can I do this?

Comment: you could put a breakpoin inside the command button's click event method...

Comment: but i need the program to continue after the new form command button is clicked without the help of the programmer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By showing your new form modally the new form is the only form in your application that responds to the user.

```
Load FrmPayment
FrmPayment.Show vbModal
```